# Can I override the asp.net localization based on an application settings

Tags: asp.net-core, localization

I have an asp.net core application that uses the built in localization successfully pulling strings from Resx files.

However, I also have an application setting in the applicationsettings.json file that changes the "Software Mode".  Depending on this mode I want to override a couple of these strings.

I was thinking I could just add an additional Resx file with just the override strings and let the system fall back to the correct culture Resx file but I am not sure how to implement this.

I have seen vague mentions of a ResourceManager but I have no idea how to implement my own custom implementation of this.

Would appreciate any assistance on this (or suggestions of an alternate method that I have not thought of).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [West Wind Globalization](https://github.com/RickStrahl/Westwind.Globalization), it should be more convenient.

> This library and tooling provides easy to use database resource managers and providers that allow you to use a database for storing localization resources. Unlike static Resx resources, database resources are dynamic, can be changed at runtime and are editable by multiple users at the same time. The custom resource managers, providers and ASP.NET Core StringLocalizers use the standard .NET resource infrastructure, so other than startup configuration there are no code changes when switching from using traditional Resx resources.